# How i get last row value in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

in my database table has 3 field id,name,roll_no. now i want to fetch last row roll_no field value and increment the value from controller  and insert the incremented value with new entry. such as last row roll_no field value is 100 after increment value current value is 101. so now save 101 roll_no value with other fields value. 
so please suggest me how can i do this

here is my model function

```
 public function last_roll_fetch(){
        return $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM student_list ORDER BY std_id DESC LIMIT 1")->result();

    }
```

Comment: Call ``->row()`` instead of ``->result()`` to get a single row

Comment: `max_row_id AS (SELECT max(row_id) from my_table) `

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to find last id inserted. You can easily fetch last id by function $this->db->insert_id(); from this you will get the roll no.

Hope this was your question!

Answer (score 0):

use row() to get single record

```
$this->db->select('*'); 
$this->db->order_by('std_id', 'DESC');
$this->db->limit('1');
$query = $this->db->get->('student_list'); 
if($query){
 return $query->row();
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).